# Other norms for lattice reduction techniques (LLL, PSLQ)?

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry

LLL and other lattice reduction techniques (such as PSLQ) try to find a short basis vector relative to the 2-norm, i.e. for a given basis that has $ \varepsilon $ as its shortest vector, $ \varepsilon \in \mathbb{Z}^n $, find a short vector s.t. $ b \in \mathbb{Z}^n, \|b\|_2 < \|c^n \varepsilon\|_2 $.

Has there been any work done to find short vectors based on other, potentially higher, norms?  Is this a meaningful question?

Comment: All norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent, so a short vector in any one norm will be a (fairly) short vector in any other norm, no?

Comment: Gerry, I think you're right about the equivalence and thus the short vector for all norms.  It looks like $ \forall p, \exists r_p, R_p s.t. r_p ||x||_p \le ||x||_2 \le R_p ||x||_p $.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The state of the art (of the possible) is covered in Khot's paper ["Inapproximability Results for Computational Problems on Lattices"](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-02295-1_14). [Here is a link](https://books.google.com/books?id=9d75m1L_GIgC&pg=PA456#v=onepage&q&f=false) to a brief section on $\ell^p$ norms.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I was hoping for better algorithms with higher norms, but this is essentially saying that they're pretty much all equivalent computationally, yes?

Answer (score 6):

There is an LLL analogue for arbitrary norms; the original paper by Lovász and Scarf can be found [here](http://mor.journal.informs.org/cgi/content/abstract/17/3/751). I recently found a [bachelor thesis](http://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/reports/reports/Vanya_Ivanova.bachelor.pdf)<sup>1</sup> on *lattice reduction in infinity norm*, which contains several other references (for example, work by Kaib and Ritter).

<sup>1</sup>Vanya Sashova Ivanova: [Lattice Basis Reduction in Infinity Norm](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Ivanova+Lattice+Basis+Reduction+in+Infinity+Norm); [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20110401070815/http://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/reports/reports/Vanya_Ivanova.bachelor.pdf), [Citeseer](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.190.5797&rep=rep1&type=pdf)